# Does Google Cloud Messaging Service allow you to send messages to iPhones?

Tags: android, iphone, google-cloud-messaging

I know that it works for Android, but I cannot find any info if they will also send messages to iPhone.  Google has been making some of their new mobile features, like their recently announced Play game service, cross platform compatible.  I am guessing this is wishful thinking, but I have not been able to find a definitive "no".

Follow up question:  Can anyone think of a hack that would allow GCMS to send to iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, you can use Google Cloud Messaging API to communicate with iOS devices, but its quite a complex process. You can read the official documentation on https://cloud.google.com/resources/articles/ios-push-notifications

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a definitive "yes" that says it does support iOS, then it may as well be a definitive "no"   Since GCM has a client component, there is no iOS support

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send push notifications to Android and iOS clients, you will need to use both GCM and iOS push services. To do so, you will also need to differentiate which OS the receiver is running, and send the notification to the right server.

In my project, Android devices are registered on my app server with version id X.Ya, and iOS devices are recognized by not having the a at the end of the version id.

Anyway, you will need a 3rd party server to do so.